# How to adjust prices according to weight on woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'd like to use Woocommerce over WordPress for my shop, but clients should be able to buy the product by either unit or weight.

If X units were bought, we must measure the actual weight of the purchase (obtained during the picking and packing of the order), and adjust the price accordingly.

Is there an easy way to do this on Woocommerce?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do your modification using follows code snippet -

```
function adjust_price_based_on_weight( $cart_object ) {
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {              
        $_product   = $cart_item['data'];
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
        $quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];

        $product_price = floatval( $_product->get_price() ); // Actual product price
        // Do your calculation based on product quantity and weight
        // for example suppose product per unit weight 2 kgs and add to cart number of unit is 3.
        $product_unit_weights = $quantity * 2; // where 2kg/per unit and $quantity is 3
        if( $product_unit_weights > 5 ) { // if units weights is greter than 5 kgs additional cost 10.
            $additionalPrice = 10;
            $_product->set_price( $product_price + $additionalPrice );
        }   
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'adjust_price_based_on_weight', 99 );
```

Comment: Thanks, though what I meant is that I want to show the customer an estimated price, then after the order is complete and prior to billing, I'd like to change the actual price according to the weight of the final order (after picking and packing). If I understand correctly, this code allows me to calculate the price per weight before completing the order. Correct?